# What is the best way to return a result from another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities (e.g Activity A, Activity B, Activity C) and Activity A calls Activity B by calling `startActivityForResult()` method and then, Activity B calls Activity C.

Activity A should receive a return value from Activity C at `onActivityResult()` method finishing Activities C and B.

For expand question, it may need more activity steps (A -> B -> C -> D -> -> ... -> return to A) to get a result and the concept of question is the first activity should receive a return value from last activity at `onActivityResult()` method.

**Process**

1. Activity A calls -> Activity B that calls -> Activity C
2. Finish activities (B, C) and remain only the Activity A.
3. A activity receive a result of C activity at `onActivityResult` method.

How can I do this?

**Apply Scenario**

- Activity A : is main activity and has a start quiz button and score edit text.
- When click the start button, start the activity B.
- Activity B : shows round 1 quiz and when finish this, continue to next round.
- Activity C : shows round 2 quiz and when finish this, continue to next round.
- Activity D : shows round 3 quiz and when finish this, close B, C, D activity and return total score (round1 + round2 + round3) to A activity.

Activity A should be able to recognize the Activity D finished event, so show a grand total score when finished D.

Comment: In my opinion we have some points:
1. in Activity A you can not receive result from Activity C by "onActivityResult", just receive it from Activity B
2. If you want A receive result from C with out B, finish middle activities and then use callback(handle, event...) to send result(data) from last activity to the first.
3. Others wise, if you still want to use "onActivityResult" you should use as A call--> B call--> C return-->B return--> A

Comment: If you can use fragments, that might make passing around values easier since you only go through one activity to the other fragment.

Comment: cricket_007/  I should solve this problem by using only the activity.  :C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: Thanks Phan Dinh. I will use your advice.

Comment: You can store score in global(in application class) variable or SharedPreference and then use it.

Comment: @KetanAhir The way to handle a finished activity D event is "onResume" method?  I'd like to show a score when finished activity D.

Comment: @S.J.Lim yes you can consider that if you are in Activity A it mean B,C,D are finished.

Answer (score 2):

You can call Activity B from A with `startActivityForResults`. Then do the same for Activity B to start Activity C. Override `onActivityResult` in Activity B and send that intent to Activity A in this method. Eg:

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent result)
 {
 super.onActivityResult(req, res, result);
 setResult(RESULT_CODE,result);
  }
```

Or you can create your own interface in class C and implement it on class A.

Comment: I have thought the same way but If it needs more activities, it seems not to be a best solution because it needs the "onActivityResult" method at each activities.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting. :D

Comment: Then, you could create an interface in the last Activity and implement that in the first Activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Classic scenario to use an event bus in android** you can either use an event bus library like otto or greenrobot or Rxjava, OR go with the classical approach of passing data through intents.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling first activity from last activity using intent as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LastActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 intent.putExtra("RESULT", "result to main activity");
 startActivity(intent);
```